Import error: Py03 modules compiled for CPython 3.8 or older may only be initialized once per interpreter process
I am trying to run remorph command. Remorph is a open source tool use to convert tradition SQL code to spark SQL code.
databricks labs remorph transpile -input-sgl C:\Users\anubhav.sharma \Downloads\emp_purge_data.sql--source snowflake --output-folder C:\Users\anubhav.sharma Downloads

I pass the input source where my tradition SQL file is present. But I am getting an error.
Previously I installed python diff version 3.13 now I am using 3.12. I checked there is no 2 python installed through python -- version
Complete error

    C:\Users\anubhav.sharma>Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma\.databricks\labs\remorph\lib\src\databricks\labs\remorph\cli.py", line 9, in <module>

from databricks.labs.remorph.reconcile.runner import ReconcileRunner File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma\.databricks\labs\remorph\lib\src\databricks\labs\remorph\reconcile\runner.py", line 13, in <module> from databricks.labs.remorph.reconcile.execute import RECONCILE_OPERATION_NAME

File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma\.databricks\labs\remorph\lib\src\databricks\labs\remorph\reconcile\execute.py", line 25, in <module> from databricks.labs.remorph.reconcile.connectors.source_adapter import create_adapter ", lin

File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma\.databricks\labs\remorph\lib\src\databricks\labs\remorph\reconcile\connectors\source_adapter.py

e 7, in <module> from databricks.labs.remorph.reconcile.connectors.snowflake import SnowflakeDataSource

File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma\.databricks\labs\remorph\lib\src\databricks\labs\remorph\reconcile\connectors\snowflake.py", line 10,

in <module>

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma.databricks\labs\remorph\state\venv\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization.

init.py", line 7, in <module>

from cryptography.hazmat.primitives. serialization import ( File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma\.databricks\labs\remorph\state\venv\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\_serialization.p

y", line 10, in <module> from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes import HashAlgorithm File "C:\Users\anubhav.sharma.databricks\labs\remorph\state\venv\Lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\hashes.py", line

9, in <module>

from cryptography.hazmat.bindings. rust import openssl as rust openssl ImportError: Py03 modules compiled for CPython 3.8 or older may only be initialized once per interpreter process

Error: exit status 1


Is the exception message you included in the title the only error message? If you're getting a full traceback, please include the whole thing (formatted as code).

I added the full error
